# finding the accuracy of the train and test model

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yrBHeozt-AImTuoINIGe40QeGQlhKrNp/view?usp=sharing) is the dataset i'm working. This dataset is the survey of VR application areas from 2019 to 2021, where N represents the "number of applications in each area" and % represents the "percentage of the total sample". I'm having problems while finding the accuracy of the train and test models.

At first libraries imported and read the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('VR_application.csv')
```

now split the data into train and test sets:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['year']], df[['N', '%']], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Creating and training the linear regression model:

```
model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

Predicting the values for training and testing sets

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)

y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Calculating the accuracy (R-squared score) for train and test sets

```
train_accuracy = r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)

test_accuracy = r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
```

checking the accuracy on train and test sets:

```
print(f"Train Accuracy: {train_accuracy}")

print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy}")
```

After doing this I get the accuracy:

```
Train Accuracy: 0.004421041085529986

Test Accuracy: -0.09666987166765573
```

Can you check my code and identify the problem I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, R2_score is the metric used to assess how well the regression model fits the observed data. In other words, The R2 score ranges from 0 to 1, where a higher value indicates a better fit of the model to the data. A score of 1 means the model perfectly explains the variability in the dependent variable, while a score of 0 means the model does not explain any of the variability. So accuracy and r2_score is completely different.
- Secondly, I can see that, you have used "train_test_split" in a wrong way.
  Use this:
  `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['N', '%'], df['year'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)`

Comment: I remove the R2_score metric and simple Creating and training the linear regression model I used this line for checking the train and test model:

`print("training set score: %f" % model.score(X_train, y_train))`

`print("test set score: %f" % model.score(X_test, y_test))`

but still, it shows: 

`training set score: 0.467743`

`test set score: 0.492105`

which is still not good.

Comment: Have you tried what I shared about the train_test_split?

Comment: By the way...you have only 2 columns and that might be not enough for model to get better results. So try creating more features.

Comment: yes, I add the train_test_split code, but still the accuracy not improving.
second, the dataset is a survey so how can I add more features?

Comment: You can create more features using your columns. For e.g. you can create polynomial features. Let's say there are 2 features: a and b. Then you can create features like: df['add'] = df['a'] + df['b'] or df['mul'] = df['a'] * df['b'] or df['poly'] = (df['a']*df['a']) + (df['b'] * df['b']) + 2 * df['a']*df['b']

Comment: thank you brother the accuracy has risen to 0.79 in training and 0.74 in testing.
can we increase this to 0.9?

Comment: - Try Standardscalar() or Robustscalar() or minmaxscalar().  - Also try changing different parameters of Linear regerssion. Also try models like Ridge regressor or Lassor regressor etc. Happy to help!